# CURL get header return different with get_headers

Tags: php, curl, header, content-type

i want to get header from file.
but CURL return value different with get_headers.

don't know why.
here's result:

with get_headers

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [1] => Content-Type: image/jpeg
    [2] => Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 11:06:07 GMT
    [3] => X-Cache-Status: HIT
    [4] => Expires: Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT
    [5] => Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
    [6] => X-Cache: HIT
    [7] => Content-Length: 120185
    [8] => Connection: close
    [9] => Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2012 08:01:15 GMT
    [10] => Server: lighttpd/1.4.26
)
```

and CURL no Content-Type ~> thats what i want

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Content-Length: 120185
    [2] => Connection: close
    [3] => Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2012 08:01:42 GMT
    [4] => Server: lighttpd/1.4.26
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
)
```

here's my get header by curl function

```
function get_headers_curl($url) 
{ 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        15); 

    $r = curl_exec($ch); 
    $r = split("\n", $r); 
    return $r; 
}
```

CURL with return Content-Type if i set

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
```

but it will return also file content (body), how to get exactly file CONTENT TYPE ONLY with CURL and without file content?

Comment: @Baba Hi, my PHP version is 5.3

Comment: Is it possible to provide the image URL for testing ??? Not ben able to replicate your issue on even PHP 5.3

Comment: Seen .. have seen the issue ... if you set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         false);` it also works ... Let me look deeper ..

Comment: i think the problem is get_headers send GET request , and CURL with CURLOPT_NOBODY the request method will be set to HEAD. if you change CURLOPT_HTTPGET = true, everything will be oK. :(

Comment: have seen that ... Ruining some test to be sure ...

Answer (score 1):

get_headers is receiving info for an image, However the other isn't. Guess you could check the url. because both have to be the same.

Comment: CURL with work if i set  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true); , but it will returns file content too ?!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get CONTENT_TYPE or other cURL infomation:

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init('link_to_file');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occured
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
```

Output:

> string(10) "image/jpeg"

Comment: OK, I edited the code to work with your case, focus at the CUSTOMREQUEST option.